# Castle ActiveRecord doesn't appear to be caching

Tags: database, caching, activerecord, castle-activerecord

I have some code that looks like this:

```
Public Shared Function FindByID(ByVal SearchID As Long) As MyClass
    If (MyClass.FindAllByProperty("ID", SearchID).Count = 0) Then Return Nothing
    Return MyClass.FindAllByProperty("ID", SearchID).First
End Function
```

If I turn on database tracing, it appears to be making two calls to the database. My understanding was that by default, ActiveRecord would cache objects. Does it not cache the results of Find calls? Presumably in this case, I can easily tweak my code to only call the method once, but in other scenarios, I might want to make the same Find() call in multiple places, and I'd need to add some additional state if I wanted to store the results of the first one.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are most likely wanting [second level caching](http://nhforge.org/blogs/nhibernate/archive/2009/02/09/quickly-setting-up-and-using-nhibernate-s-second-level-cache.aspx) from nHibernate.  You would need to do something like this in your config:

```
<configSections>
        <section name="syscache" type="NHibernate.Caches.SysCache.SysCacheSectionHandler,NHibernate.Caches.SysCache"/>

</configSections>

    <syscache>
        <cache region="YourEntityHere" expiration="86400" priority="1"/>
        <cache region="YourOtherEntity" expiration="86400" priority="1"/>
    </syscache>
```

Comment: A lot of the code in the link you included looked like stuff that would be wrapped by Castle. I tried making changes in the config like you had indicated, as well as outlined at http://www.castleproject.org/activerecord/documentation/v1rc1/advanced/secondLevelCache.html, but don't see a change in behavior.